# Empty body content on TYPO3 page

Tags: typo3

Encountered an issue today where I made tweaks to the a TYPO3 page and the page became blank. The `<body>` tag was empty!

I fixed it by clearing cache, but I also found another page with the same problem later on.

Doing some research I found that the page is empty on the `cache_pages` table.

What is causing it? I am using TYPO3 4.5.6

Comment: if it happen again, have a look at typo3conf/temp_CACHED_*ext_localconf.php befor you clear the cache again. Check if the serialized array is quotet (which should not happen): $TYPO3_LOADED_EXT = unserialize(stripslashes('a:95:{s:3:\"cms\";a:7:{s:4:\"type\";s:1:\"S\";s:11:\"siteRelPath\";s:17:\"typo3/sysext/cms/\";s:12:\"typo3RelPath\";s:11:\"sysext/cms/\";s:17:\"ext_localconf.php\";s:59:\"/daten/ht

Comment: cache_pages is empty, after you cleared the cache. If it stays empty, you may have deactivated caching for all sites via config.no_cache=1 or compare database in install-tool.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me. and the cause was, in the fluid template?
Instead of using fluid template, i just use the regular html tag if you didn't initiate the view helper or something in your form.

Comment: Could you be more specific en your answer.

Answer (score -1):

This usually happens, if you don't have a `PAGE` TLO.

Make sure your main template includes something like:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = Hello world!
}
```

You might have cleared it by accident.

Comment: That's not the case though, all other pages work, and the pages that have empty body work after a clear cache.